# Expose a class as STA COM

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a little c# class that I need to expose as COM.  THe tool that will use the COM object requires that I support STA.  Is there anything special that I need to do with my COM object?

(I know about the STAThread attribute, but (unless I'm wrong)  It is for indicating that a thread of execution in .net is to be STA compatible, and not for indicating that my COM object needs to be compatible).

Here's my declaration so far.  Do you see anything that I need to add?

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestClass1))]
    [Guid("093A3701-2C53-4A31-97C5-0F3C205E5B4C")]
    public class Class1: ITestClass1 {..}

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8D52F785-CDD8-4248-8AB7-97B8C19DE59B")]
    public interface ITestClass1 {..}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A COM server advertises the threading model it requires with a registry entry named ThreadingModel.  Single threaded is the default if the registry key is missing or when it is set to "Apartment".

Regasm.exe sets this key to "Both".  Which means that your server is declared to be compatible with both STA threads and MTA threads.  Somewhat in keeping with .NET code in general, it supports threading but with the requirement that you have to take care of thread-safety.  Changing this is very awkward, you have to write your own registration procedure and annotate it with the [ComRegisterFunction] attribute.

The simple approach is leave the key set to "Both" and to check the apartment state in your class constructor.  Use Thread.GetCurrentThread().GetApartmentState().  If you get MTA then throw an exception to tell the client that you don't support multi-threading.  Lots of .NET classes do this.

Comment: Slight inaccuracy: `STA` is not the default, and a missing `ThreadingModel` registry key does not set the threading model to `Apartment`, but to the more restrictive `Main Thread Apartment` model. A "Main Thread" object is an STA object, with the additional constraint that it will be created in the main thread of the process regardless of which thread creates the object. The "main thread" is supposed to be the "first thread" in the process to call `CoInitialize()` and friends, but I don't know what happens if the first CoInitializeEx() call is for a MTA.

Comment: People do get confused about the distinction between what a COM object needs and what a thread provides.  This question is only about the object.  STA and MTA are terms that only apply to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726624/specify-apartment-state-to-use-when-instantiating-out-of-proc-com-object/5727733#5727733) for an example of a ComRegisterFunction that does the necessary registry voodoo. There are a few cases where you might want this - e.g. when you want to ensure that your threads are STA so you can interact with other COM objects that require use only by STA threads.